# How do I use methods in a namespace that my space's parent's superclass has?

Tags: ruby

I have a `Book < LibraryItem`

and a `Book::Page`, which is defined as

```
class Book
  class Page
```

in models/book/page.rb

`LibraryItem` has a method called `can_edit?`

But my `Book::Page.new.can_edit?` returns no method error...

how do I include the instance methods from `LibraryItem` in my namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns an error because `Page` does not have a `can_edit?` method. A `Book` has a `Page` class, but `Page` is not a subclass of `Library` item (only `Book` is). So `can_edit?` is valid for `Book` but not for `Page`.

Try

```
p Book::Page.superclass
```

And you will get `Object`

Comment: Cool, So I change it to be Book::Page << LibraryItem, that worked! =D

Comment: Does it make sense in your case for Page to extend LibraryItem (I don't know the semantics of your LibraryItem class). Is a page a library item?

Comment: Well, in my actual code Page is a Template, and Templates can exist independently of my object represented by a book here... I should probably come up with a better analogy for StackOverflow =D

Answer (score 1):

The root issue is that ruby does not support multiple inheritance.  Questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828956/techniques-to-overcome-the-single-inheritance-issue) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095159/multiple-inheritance-type-class-inheritance-in-ruby) point to the idea that you should consider pulling functionality out to modules that you can include arbitrarily in class definitions.

Comment: In this case, I feel like modules are less semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby access the parent methods by default, if you run this code on an irb console:

```
class LibraryItem
  def can_edit?
    true
  end
end

class Book < LibraryItem
  class Page
  end
end
```

you can easily access to can_edit? method, just doing:

```
book = Book.new
book.can_edit?
```

but from Page class you can't access LibraryItem methods, because it isn't on the inheritance chain

tip: for namespacing use modules not nested classes.

Comment: endend up making both classes inherit from LibraryItem. These aren't the actual class names in my actual code, but it makes more semantic sense to use Inheritance.